# Changing data time zones for time series data pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, time

I have a dictionary of data that has Time and Frequency as shown below.

```
dictionary = {'7:00 pm': 16, ' 6:00 AM': 102, '6:00 PM': 7, '11:00 AM': 7, ' 9:00 AM': 87, '9:00 PM': 19, ' 8:00AM': 15, '8:00PM': 13, ' 7:00AM': 12, ' 5:00AM': 243, '5:00PM': 1, ' 4:00AM': 57, '13:00 PM': 4, '4:00 PM': 10, ' 3:00 AM': 87, '3:00PM': 1, '12 Noon': 24, '10:00AM': 45, ' 2:00AM': 9, '2:00PM': 1, ' 1:00AM': 12}
```

The time values are in UTC as the data was obtained from Power Virtual Agents that use UTC time.
It is easy to change such a small dictionary by simply adding 3 hours to each value but is there a function to change data from one time zone to another?

Comment: `The time values are in UTC`. Is possible change sample data for `UTC datetime`s? And add expected output?

Comment: Also I think pandas is here not necessary, so removed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you can use `pytz` and other external modules, this is a more straight forward solution:

```
pip install pytz tzlocal
```

then :

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone

#timezones
local = get_localzone()
utc = pytz.utc
cet = timezone('CET')

#get now time in different zones
print(datetime.now(local))
print(datetime.now(cet))
print(datetime.now(utc))

#convert local time now to CET
print(datetime.now(local).astimezone(cet))
print(datetime.now(cet).astimezone(utc))
```